# What is the point where you can make a U-turn called?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What is the point where you can make a U-turn called? Can we use "turnaround"?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it better belongs on the engineering site in the Stack Exchange network (https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with a "transportation engineering" tag.

Comment: This should be answered by referring to your local area driving regulations, such as a driver's handbook. Physically, it is just a "break in the median".

Comment: @user3169 I would suggest that Mike's question could refer to a wide variety of places. Do they wish to describe a part of that image that was posted, and if so, which part, exactly? Does the "can" in "can make a U-turn" mean legally permissible? If so, how specific and accurate need be the answer, in what jurisdiction, with exactly those road markings and no signs, etc.? Further: in what variety or varieties of English, how technical or conversational, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The descriptive phrase you may be looking for is

> **a break in the median**

or

> **median u-turn**

The "***median***" is what separates the two sides of a major road and may be fairly wide.

Comment: "The descriptive phrase you may be looking for" Isn't there a specific word for it? Can we use "turnaround"?

Comment: "***Turnaround***" is not specific to a median, it could also just be an extra wide part of a road with no median where a car can more easily turn.  Your situation has two distinct parts: a median and a u-turn.

Answer (score 0):

In British English the land between the two lanes is called the *central reservation* and the wall or fence put on that land is called the *traffic barrier* So this could be described as "a break in the traffic barrier".

On UK motorways making a U-Turn is strictly forbidden, and there are no breaks in the traffic barriers. On some dual-carriageways, there might be a break in the central reservation to allow traffic from a side road to access both carriageways, but there are usually signs prohibiting U-turns at these points too.

In American use "[turnaround](http://www.27east.com/news/article.cfm/Hampton-Bays/547525/State-DOT-Installs-Sunrise-Highway-Turnaround-At-The-Request-Of-Inlet-Road-East-Residents)" may be possible, but that is more often used for the [area at the end of a driveway or cul-de-sac](http://elpaso-tx.elaws.us/code/coor_title9_ch9.52_sec9.52.200) rather than on a road.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you *can* use [**turnaround**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turnaround):

> **3** : a space permitting the turning around of a vehicle

It is a more general term, however. If somebody simply says "turnaround," it may not be clear that they are referring to "a break in the median" specifically (as opposed to a different type of turnaround).